# How can I update the value of key in OrderedDict in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ordereddict

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict([('foo', 123),
                 ('bar', 456)])
```

So I want to check if there's a `foo` key in `d` and if there's then I'd like to rewrite it as a single value of a list for a new hardcoded key:

```
print(d)

ordereddict([('bar', 456), ('newCoolHardcodedKey', [ordereddict([('foo', 123)])])])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generating expression (like a list comprehension, but returns an iterator instead of storing the temporary list in memory) to do this:

```py
d = OrderedDict(
    (
        ("newCoolHardcodedKey", OrderedDict([item])) if item[0] == "foo" else item
        for item in d.items()
    )
)

print(d)

OrderedDict([('newCoolHardcodedKey', OrderedDict([('foo', 123)])), ('bar', 456)])
```

The dict being ordered, the new element is where `foo` was.

If you need the new element to go to the end, it might be easiest to test if `d["foo"]` exists, and if so append the new ordered dict with its hard-coded key and delete the original entry for `foo`:

```py
if "foo" in d:
    d["newCoolHardcodedKey"] = OrderedDict([("foo", d["foo"])])
    del d["foo"]

print(d)

OrderedDict([('bar', 456), ('newCoolHardcodedKey', OrderedDict([('foo', 123)]))])
```

**Performance considerations**

If `d` is large in your real application, the second solution is much better since it changes `d` in place instead of making a copy.